# Elements with order 3 in group $F_{16}/\{0\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, finite-fields

If you have the finite field $GF(16)$ and you define the group $GF(16)/\{0\},*$ this group is cyclic. I need to determine how many elements in this group have order 3. Of course you could just try out all elements but I wonder if there isn't a more efficient technique. I don't need to know which elements have order 3, just how many.

Comment: Martini's answer (or DonAntonio's) is perfect for your purposes. If you actually want to find those elements, then you can take a peek [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/591254/11619).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb F_{16} - \{0\}$ has 15 elements. A cyclic group with $15$ elements is isomorphic to $\def\Z{\mathbb Z}\Z/(15) \cong \Z/(3) \times \Z/(5)$. An element $(a,b)$ of the latter group has order $3$ if $b = 0$ and $a \ne 0$. Hence there are two of them.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Any cyclic group of order $\;n\;$ has one **unique** subgroup of order $\;k\;$ for any $\;k\mid n\;$ .